# Installing Flutter using Homebrew

Tags: flutter, terminal, operating-system, homebrew, apple-m1

I would like to install Flutter on my Apple M1 machine using [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/flutter). But I am a bit hesitant because I am not sure if this will provide any benefits or it will create more trouble (e.g. permission issues). An alternative way would to be install Flutter using its installer from its [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install).

My question is, is there a recommended way to install Flutter on an Apple M1 macbook? I could not find any docs regarding installing Flutter using Homebrew.

Comment: In the docs(From Flutter) it shows a way to install it which many users used before you. May I ask why its not sufficient for you?

Comment: @DEFL Not a particular reason to be honest beside having a preference towards using brew. Mainly i wanted to see if there is preferred installation way for an M1 machine.

Comment: https://fvm.app/  maybe you need this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Update October 2023 – Apple M1/M2

I ended up installing Flutter in with the following steps:

1. Install `Homebrew` (if you dont already have)* - [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install `fvm` using `Homebrew` - [install fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation/)

```
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
```

3. Install your wanted `flutter` version through `fvm` - [fvm documentation](https://fvm.app/docs/guides/basic_commands)

```
fvm install stable  # Installs latest stable version of flutter
```

4. Run `fvm doctor` to ensure it is installed
5. Set the default flutter version on your machine:

```
fvm global stable  # sets your default flutter to the installed stable version
```

6. After the previous command you might see in the output to change your flutter path to `/Users/<YOUR_USER>/fvm/default/bin`. In that case from the root of your user:

```
nano .zshrc
```

7. Then paste the following in your `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<YOUR_USER>/fvm/default/bin"
```

8. Then save (`control + o`) then hit enter and then exit (`control + x`)
9. Close and reopen your terminal and check the flutter installation with `fvm flutter --version`
10. Run `fvm flutter doctor` to resolve and install any missing components

#### If `fvm flutter doctor` had such a warning:

```
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.1.5/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/<YOUR_USER>/fvm/versions/stable. Consider adding /Users/<YOUR_USER>/fvm/versions/stable/bin to the front of your path.
```

You can resolve it by uninstalling `dart` from `brew` since flutter sdks are shipped already with dart:

```
brew uninstall dart
```

Comment: Worth noting that when doing an initial Flutter setup in this way, `flutter doctor` will warn that Dart on your path will resolve to the version in `opt/homebrew/Cellar`, which is not inside the current Flutter SDK checkout on your path.

Comment: I also had flutter installed using homebrew earlier, so even after `brew uninstall dart` an old dart version remained in `$PATH`. I had to `brew uninstall flutter` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 11):

@ilpianoforte Does a great job outlining the steps, but I needed to do an additional step for macOS 13.x.  So, I thought I would consolidate here.

To install Flutter via Homebrew.

1. Install `Homebrew`

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install `fvm` with `Homebrew` (this manages multiple versions of `Flutter`)

```
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
```

3. Install the latest stable version of `Flutter`

```
fvm install stable
```

4. Set default version of Flutter: (-> `$HOME/fvm/default`)

```
fvm global
```

5. Append the path to `Flutter` to `PATH` by copying the line below into `.zshrc` (located in the home directory).  IMPORTANT: Make sure to replace `[USER_HERE]` with your user name.

```
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/fvm/default/bin"
```

6. Reload `.zshrc`

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

7. Optional: Test `Flutter` installation.

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Should the PATH setting here be `/Users/[USER_HERE]/fvm/versions/stable/bin`? I tried the above and got a `no such file or directory`.

Comment: @PaulGrimes You replace [USER_HERE] with you user name.  For example, it could be /Users/paul/fvm/versions/stable/bin

Comment: For me @PaulGrimes their suggestion worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple. Just run

```
brew install flutter
```

Answer (score -1):

directly run brew

```
install --cask flutter
```

and then you get your flutter SDK

Comment: I wanted to be able to use several sdk versions and in that case fvm would be useful

Comment: Year, you're right! Fvm is a great tool to manage flutter sdk multiple-versions.