How do I locate my Flutter SDK if I have installed using homebrew?
I want to locate my flutter sdk, which I have installed using HomeBrew.
Expecting to get flutter skd
enter image description here
What are the next steps to have my flutter project running on VSCode.
I want to locate my flutter sdk, which I have installed using HomeBrew.
Expecting to get flutter skd.
What are the next steps to have my flutter project running on VSCode.

you have to find where did you place your sdk. then locate it using locate sdk. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782659/installing-flutter-using-homebrew

run this command brew list --cask, look for the line flutter, it will be something like /opt/homebrew/opt/flutter there you will find your sdk location
